# Laravel eloquent where condition parent/children with 3rd model many to many

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I have 2 models `User` and `Modules`
`Modules` has a recursive parent/children relation having Many childrens (`SubModules`).

In other hand a User can Have Many Modules and Many Submodules (permissions to access them) so they're in a N to N table `users_modules`

So I want to extract all Modules of the users, but these Modules only needs to include subModules related with the user.

For Now I have something like this in my controller:

```
auth()->user()->modules->toArray();
```

but I don't know how can I filter those subModules.

This are my Models (without any changes because all I've tried is not working):

**User**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
   ...
    public function modules()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Module::class, 'modules_users')->where('group', null)->with('subModules');
    }
```

**Module**

```php
class Module extends Model
{
   ...

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'modules_users');
    }

    public function subModules()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Module::class, 'group');
    }

    public function parent(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Module::class, 'group');
    }
}
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Could you share the model's relationship definition (`User::modules()`, `Module::users()`, `Module::subModules()`, etc...). That would be the first step to actually understand what the problem is. If you are trying to access a relationship of a relationship there are a couple of things you can do.

Comment: Thanks @Sam for your answer. I've edited my question including my Models and they relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Edit

Based on the comments we have had back and forth, I think I *understand* the problem you are having. You need to access the `user.modules.subModules` where `subModules` belong to the user and maintain the related tree of your modules object.

The good news is that Laravel does allows query logic injection in these `with()` calls. You can do something like:

```php
$userId = 5; // auth()->id();
$user = User::query()->where('id', $userId)
    ->with('modules.subModules', function ($query) {
        $query->whereHas('users', fn ($subQuery) => $subQuery->where('id', $userId));
    })
    ->first();

dd($user->toArray());
```

This outputs locally for me the following object:

[image]

Now just as a proof-of-concept, if I attach another `subModule` with a `parent_id` set to 1, I should see that in my `sub_modules` object

[image]

My recommendation does stand to look at the Library I recommended in my original answer, but the above query is fairly simple as it stands, there are limitations to how it's fetching the data and creating your object, but this all depends on how complex you will need to get.

---

## Original Answer

There are a couple of solutions here, and I think the best approach will depend a little on your data structure.

The easiest and probably the best way you are trying to access the data would be to use Laravel's `.` syntax in the first parameter of your `with()` call.

```php
$user = User::inRandomOrder()->with('modules.subModules')->first()
```

[image]

The main downside to this approach is the depth of your `subModules()`. This would be limited to the immediate children of any module the user may belong to.

If I update the query with another level of `subModules` you can see that my module 6 has their own children.

```php
$user::query()->where('id', 5)->with('modules.subModules.subModules')->first();
```

[image]

Another possible solution would be to at a 3rd party library to help you access nested relationships easier.

Take a look at [`kalnov/nestedset`](https://packagist.org/packages/kalnoy/nestedset), there's a lot there, but it would add the following methods to your models:

```php
$result = Category::whereDescendantOf($node)->get();
$result = Category::whereNotDescendantOf($node)->get();
$result = Category::orWhereDescendantOf($node)->get();
$result = Category::orWhereNotDescendantOf($node)->get();
$result = Category::whereDescendantAndSelf($id)->get();

// Include target node into result set
$result = Category::whereDescendantOrSelf($node)->get();
```

Which my guess that is probably what you are looking for in an application context where the content the user is trying to access has be traced back to the user in some way. That can easily get hairy if the user can belong to different levels of Modules as well.

Comment: Hey @Sam thanks for your answer... But... your solution doesn't solve my problem...
With my code (or yours) I have a **User** (OK) with his **Modules** (OK) and **ALL SUBMODULES** of the Module (NOT OK) 

I need a User with His Modules and **ONLY SUBMODULES of the USER**.
All Modules and submodules User can see are included in relatation table called `user_modules`

Comment: @ElenaMartínCastillo then I am confused as to why `User::query()->with('modules')` is not what you are looking for. A `subModule` is just a `module` and with these relationships you can just get the user's modules, it shouldn't matter whether it's a parent/child relationship.

Comment: Well @Sam is true, this query extract only modules you need. But I would like to have modules "ordered" as a module, submodule tree, having 1st level Modules and then submodules as children of those 1st level Modules

Comment: @ElenaMartínCastillo I just updated my answer.  I think I understand what you are trying to achieve, hopefully the above will be helpful

Comment: Pictures of text are not helpful. Please copy and paste the content into the answer instead.

Comment: It's just a dump of content @miken32 , don't need to be able to copy/paste, also local data that I put together, idek if that is the correct data structure.

Comment: Thanks @Sam with your help, I've found a solution.